# Two-way SMS by pulling data from an excel sheet based on the phone number

Tags: python, sms

I am trying to use an API where people would answer to a text either saying only Y or N and then based on which they say they would get a text back giving personalized information such as what you see in the code with their first name, appointment date, etc. I want to make it so when getting this information I would search for the senders phone number on an excel sheet, and look x amount of columns over for each of the definitions in the dict as presented under 'personalisation {}' in the code so each text is sent with the correct information for each individual person. Here is what I have so far as the basis of analyzing the text message and formulating a response back but personalising the message is the issue I am having so far.

```
@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def incoming_sms():
body = request.values.get('Body', None)

for _yes = ['y','yes','Yes','Y']
for _no = ['n','No','no','N']

if body in for_yes:
    response = notifications_client.send_sms_notification(
        phone_number = 'From Excel',
        template_id = '____', 
    personalisation = {
        'first_name': '',
        'appointment_date': '',
        'GP Name': '',
```

Comment: Actually I believe your two for statements are your problem. What exactly are you trying to do there?

Comment: @BoboDarph well I am trying to respond to the text messages based on a couple different texts the person might respond with. The text would end with "Reply Y for yes or N for no" but its possible people would reply with a 'yes' or a 'no' regardless and want to still pool those into the group of texts that would get a personalised reply back

Comment: There's a big space character in the name of your "for_yes" and "for_no" variables. If you do that, your interpreter will consider whatever comes after the for statement as a for block. Also your "personalisation" dictionary never closes. That's also a problem.

Comment: @BoboDarph Yeah I fixed the two issues I just cut off the bottom part of the code by accident. Do you have any suggestions on parsing data from an excel sheet in order to fill in the personalisation dictionary for every text?